# How to get skype status without allowing "allow my online status to be shown on the web" in skype application

Tags: skype

How to get skype status without allowing "allow my online status to be shown on the web" in skype application ?
It show status online, only when i "allow my online status to be shown on the web" manually in "Tools>Options>Privacy".
Is there any way i can check without allowing it ?